# JNI fails with 'Error occurred during initialization of VM'

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

Per JNI documentation, I only need jvm.dll when trying to launch a JVM instance. However, if I simply put jvm.dll in the folder where my application lives, I get following error:

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries

The only way I can get my code to run is if I put jdk\jre\bin\server folder (which contains jvm.dll) on my environment path. It seems like JNI depends on some other dlls and jar files in jdk\jre\bin and jdk\jre\lib folders respectively. I, in fact, tested this by copying this folder elsewhere, using that folder in my environment path, and then slowly taking away files/folders other than jvm.dll until it stops working.

Can anyone explain what I am trying to do wrong? How can I get my code to only depend on jvm.dll and nothing else. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can't have your code depend only on jvm.dll. jvm.dll is only sort of a gateway to the whole of the JRE. You can't just pick some files and copy them somewhere. If you want to run Java you need a complete Java Runtime Environment.

Leave jvm.dll where it is and load it from there. To achieve that you could put the folder where the DLL is in the PATH. Or you could determine its location from the registry and get the jvm functions with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

If you later want/have to ship your application with a private JRE, you can leave out *some* files. Oracle has a documentation somewhere, about which files can be left out, but I don't have the link handy, and it's only a few files anyway.